# How to fix redux error "Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: ''"

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title and I genuinely don't have a clue as to what to change about my code. I have other projects with the redux set up exactly like this with no issue.

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Main from './components/Main';
import {store} from './store'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Main />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

store.js

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import likeReducer from './slices/likeSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    like: likeReducer
  },
})
```

likeSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const likeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'likes',
  initialState: {
    posts: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    addPost: (state, action) => {
      state.posts = [...state.posts, action.payload];
    },
    removePost: (state, action) => {
      state.posts = state.posts.filter(post => post !== action.payload);
    },
  },
})

export const {addPost, removePost} = likeSlice.actions;

export default {likeReducer} = likeSlice.reducer;
```

At first I thought maybe it just needed me to add more reducers or actions but that did nothing. Like I said, I have a few other projects that have redux set up exactly like this and they don't get this issue. There have been other times when I've gotten this error but they just sort of fixed themselves and I don't know how. I'm using expo snack and in my experience it has some issues so I wouldn't doubt if that's why it keeps giving me this error but I would really appreciate some help. I've looked at some other posts here but everyone writes their redux with switch statements and I don't really understand how that way of doing redux works or how I could apply what people suggested to those posts to my own code.

Answer (score 0):

The default export of the likes reducer is incorrect. Don't try to default export an undefined destructured reference, just default export the reducer function directly.

Update

```js
export default { likeReducer } = likeSlice.reducer;
```

to

```js
export default likeSlice.reducer; // <-- default export
```

Now the default export will work as a default import when creating the store.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import likeReducer from './slices/likeSlice'; // <-- default import

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    like: likeReducer
  },
});
```

Comment: just tried that but i'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: @LiamHorton Have you completely killed and restarted the app? I didn't see any other overt issues with the code you shared. Could you share a link to your repo if it's public, and/or try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: the link for the sandbox is too long for a comment, what username should i send the invite to?

Comment: The link should be fairly short and manageable, something like `"https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-zebra-rtk3j7"` you might have some additional params/etc that aren't necessary.

Comment: "https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/dogapp-g6rqwr" alright this should be it

Comment: @LiamHorton I copy/pasted your Redux code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-fix-redux-error-expected-the-root-reducer-to-be-a-function-instead-rec-pfr86z) to isolate it and get it running, and to my surprise, your reducer export that I thought was invalid is actually working. Is this an Expo project you are working on? If it's not too much trouble, could you create an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) of your code so there's an actual running demo that produces the error?

Comment: "https://snack.expo.dev/@memememememe/dogs4u" not sure if this link is accessible to you but here is the expo snack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256262/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-liam-horton).